# Trying to build a table with expandable rows (embedded table) using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to have a table with rows that expand.
So each row of the table could be "pressed" and the row is expanded and another "embedded" table is displayed.
I am trying to implement this on top of the JQuery accordion.
I tried the following but it does not work at all:

```
<html lang="en">  
<head>  
  <meta charset="utf-8">  
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">   
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">    
  <script>    
  $(function() {  
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();  
  });  
  </script>  
</head>  
<body>  

<div id="accordion">  
  <!-- <h3>Section 1</h3> -->   
<table>  
  <tr><td><label>User</label></td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>   
  <div>  
    <p>  
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer  
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit  
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut  
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.  
    </p>  
  </div>  
  <h3>Section 4</h3>  
  <div>  
    <p>  
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus  
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in  
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia  
    mauris vel est.  
    </p>  
  </div>  
</table>  
</div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Am I using the wrong widget? What am I messing up here?

Answer (score 0):

Here i added accordion sample for you. Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks.

```
<html lang="en">  
<head>  
  <meta charset="utf-8">  
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">   
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
 #table tbody .accordion:hover td:first-child, #applicantTable tbody .accordion.active td:first-child{ 
            border-left:3px solid #000; border-top:none; float:left;  overflow: hidden; padding-left: 5px; width:100%;
        }
#table tbody tr td{
    background-color:#ccc;
}
</style>
  <script>    
  $(function() {
    var $list = $('.list');    
    $list.find("tr").not('.accordion').hide();
    $list.find("tr").eq(0).show();
    $list.find(".accordion").click(function(){ 
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1) ;    
    $list.find('.accordion').not(this).siblings().fadeOut(500);
    $(this).siblings().fadeToggle(500);
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $list.find('.accordion').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $list.find('.accordion').not(this).css("opacity", 0.33);
        $list.find('.accordion').not(this).hover(function(){
            $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);},
            function(){$(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.33);
        });
    });    
});  
  </script>  
</head>  
<body>  <table class="table list" id="table">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                    <th>Table</th>                  
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="">
                <tr class="accordion">
                    <td>Table Row1 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="" style="border-left: 5px solid #000;"> 
                    <td colspan="5">>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vitae diam vitae nisl euismod posuere ut sit amet lectus. Mauris sit amet pharetra augue. Integer dapibus quam in nisi tempor ac egestas velit sollicitudin. Pellentesque ac diam eros. Morbi at tellus eu ipsum lobortis posuere eu eget erat.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr class="accordion">
                    <td>Table Row 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="" style="border-left: 5px solid #000;"> 
                    <td colspan="5">>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vitae diam vitae nisl euismod posuere ut sit amet lectus. Mauris sit amet pharetra augue. Integer dapibus quam in nisi tempor ac egestas velit sollicitudin. Pellentesque ac diam eros. Morbi at tellus eu ipsum lobortis posuere eu eget erat.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="accordion">
                    <td>Table Row 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="" style="border-left: 5px solid #000;"> 
                    <td colspan="5">>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vitae diam vitae nisl euismod posuere ut sit amet lectus. Mauris sit amet pharetra augue. Integer dapibus quam in nisi tempor ac egestas velit sollicitudin. Pellentesque ac diam eros. Morbi at tellus eu ipsum lobortis posuere eu eget erat.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr class="accordion">
                    <td>Table Row 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="" style="border-left: 5px solid #000;"> 
                    <td colspan="5">>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vitae diam vitae nisl euismod posuere ut sit amet lectus. Mauris sit amet pharetra augue. Integer dapibus quam in nisi tempor ac egestas velit sollicitudin. Pellentesque ac diam eros. Morbi at tellus eu ipsum lobortis posuere eu eget erat.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>

</body>  
</html>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/EfeTN/181/)